# AJAX Loader doesn't stay untill the new content is loaded

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am using AJAX functionality to make my WordPress pages load in real time. I use the following approach to make it load in real time

`var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #container';

        $('#container').slideUp('300',loadContent);

        $('#load').remove();

        $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');

        $('#load').fadeIn('normal');

        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);

        function loadContent() {

            $('#container').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())

        }

        function showNewContent() {

            $('#container').slideDown('400',hideLoader());

        }

        function hideLoader() {

            $('#load').fadeOut('normal');

        }

        return false;`

The problem i am facing is that the loading... text appear for half a second and the old content appears again.. and then after 4-5 seconds, it just replaces the new content with the old one.
How can i keep the Loading Text until the content is fully loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not perfectly clear to me,

But,

```
$('#container').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
```

should be changed to

```
$('#container').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent)
```

and,

```
$('#container').slideDown('400',hideLoader());
```

to

```
$('#container').slideDown('400',hideLoader);
```

We pass the function reference ( we dont call them )

Also, I dont think there's any `.fadeIn('normal')`.

It would be either `.fadeIn('slow')` or `.fadeIn('fast')`

Also,

lines following this

```
$('#container').slideUp('300',loadContent);
```

do not wait for animation completion. They gets called instantly.

I guess, you would want them to put in `loadContent` function

Comment: Issue solved :)
this is exactly what i was looking for. 
Thanks Alot